# Socket Injection

Tags: python, sockets

(Theoretical)
Ok, so we have our data. Our data is a raw DNS Packet data, with all the information that is needed to tell the DNS to connect to a server, including the header, etc

```
[Data]
```

But the socket that we are allowed to use is only AF_INET and SOCK_DGRM. So when it sends it will not end up using the data as we intended, it would be like:

```
[HEADER]
[Data]
[END HEADER]
```

My question is: Is it possible to include some sort of data, so that when the socket sends, it would make it a raw socket? (AKA Socket Injection?)
Example:

```
[HEADER]
[Fake END HEADER w/ Data]
[END HEADER]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to include some sort of data, so that when the socket sends, it would make it a raw socket?

No it's not. By design the data you write to a normal socket (i.e. SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_STREAM) are just the payload of the UDP or TCP packet and gets not interpreted in any way by the kernel or by Python.
Thus if this would be possible then it would be a bug.